# X second delay between two tasks c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I want to delay 80 milliseconds between task 1 and task 2.
But here Task 1 and Task 2 run together.
my code:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SendBuyOrder();
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(Task1(cts.Token), Task2(cts.Token));
            //await Task.WhenAll(Task1(cts.Token));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


    }

    public void send(int t)
    {
        txtResult.AppendText("Task" + t + ": " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
        txtResult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        txtResult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public async Task Task1(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32(txtRepeatInterval.Text), token);
            send(1);
        }
    }

    public async Task Task2(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32(txtRepeatInterval.Text), token);
            send(2);
        }
    }
```

Here, Task 1 and Task 2 are run together, and 80 milliseconds after Task 1 is run again. I want task 2 to be performed 80 milliseconds after starting task 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ewn.png)

Comment: As a side note, `Task1` and `Task2` are not appropriate names for methods in general, and for asynchronous methods in particular. Methods names should be [verbs or verb phrases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-methods), and asynchronous methods should have the [Async suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make one task that does both:

```cs
public async Task Task3(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32(txtRepeatInterval.Text), token);
        send(1);
        await Task.Delay(80, token);
        send(2);
    }
}
```